# Why do i get this have(1) error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I get an rspec error that i would not expect and i end up checking in another way. However, i would like to know why it does not work. The error is like :

```
 Failure/Error: @user.should have(1).work_shift
 RuntimeError:
   expected work_shift to be a collection but it does not respond to #length or #size
```

And the spec is :

```
        it "should create the work shift" do
            post :start, :work_hours => 6
            flash[:error].should == nil
            @user.should have(1).work_shift
            response.should redirect_to labor_url                       
        end
```

Why do i get that error ? (User has_one work_shift, the association works fine)

Comment: You would have to go into rspec-expectations and change the matcher to to accept non-array arguments. Other options: "@user.work_shift. should be", ".should be_a_kind_of WorkShift", or ".should be_a WorkShift".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want:

```
@user.work_shift.should_not == nil
```

which could also be written as:

```
@user.work_shift.should be_present
```

Comment: yeap, should be_present is just what i need thanx :)

Answer (score 1):

```
expected work_shift to be a collection
```

Since User has only one work_shift

```
@user.work_shift
```

does not give an array.

The RSpec message says

```
but it does not respond to #length or #size
```

So that matcher is looking for an array-like object.

Comment: So, have(1) does not work at all ? I see your point, it's indeed not an array, but how can it be fixed ?